# Access array index from output of helper in handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Using handlebars I am trying to log the element at index `1` of an array. The array is the result of the `split` helper. However, I can't figure out  how to do this. Here's my attempt:

```
{{log (split message '==FUBC==').[1]}}
```

However, this results in an error:

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error
    Error: Uncaught error: Parse error on line 4:
...message '==FUBC==')).[1]}}
```

Is it possible to do what I'm attempting with handlebars? I think one solution would be to use another helper, for example `itemAt`, like this:

```
{{log (itemAt (split message '==FUBC==') 1)}}
```

However, the framework I am working with doesn't implement this helper and I am not able to add new ones. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks. That didn't work. I get a parse error from the first double parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways, but there might be better ways (*haven't used handlebars recently*)

Either use `#with` to get the array and then access its elements with `[]`

```
{{#with (split title "==FUBC==")}}
    {{log [0]}}
{{/with}}
```

or directly use the `lookup` helper.

```
{{log (lookup (split title "==FUBC==") 1)}}
```